# gsutil - How to copy/download all files from Google private cloud?

Tags: gsutil

- Google Play Developer account reports are stored on private Google Cloud Storage bucket.
- Every Google Play Developer account has Google Cloud Storage bucket ID

So to access I have installed gsutil on my windows machine.

Now I am using this command to copy all files from bucket

```
    gsutil cp -r dir gs://[bucket_id]
```

its says

```
CommandException: No URLs matched
```

When I list all directories on bucket, this command works

```
    gsutil ls gs://[bucket_id]
```

Can anyone help here to understand the gsutil exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is because destination URL is missing

It should be like...

`gsutil cp -r dir gs://[bucket_id] [destination_bucket_url]`

Comment: Note: The destination can also be a folder on the local machine.